# Limit Linq result columns for GridView Using Custom Type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In this question the answer also had the option of
"Or create a class and return list of that instead of using Anonymous type."

[Limit Linq result columns for GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867210/limit-linq-result-columns-for-gridview)

Could someone show me how to do that?

Comment: You want someone to show you how to create a class? If you don't know how to do that it is probably best that you do a little more research like read a book on the basics or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anonymous type:

```
var query = (from dins in h.Dinners
                 where dins.Title == "New York"
                 select new { dins.Title, dins.DinnerID });
```

custom type:

```
public class myType
{
public string Title { get; set; }
public int DinnerID { get; set; }
}

select new { etc }
```

becomes

```
select new myType { Title = dins.Title, DinnerID = dins.DinnerID }
```

You can omit the Title = and DinnerID = IF the property names are the same, but I've included them for clarity

- This is entirely off the top of my head, I make no assertion that it's compilable/working code for your exact needs!